# Do any vendors sell good mining rigs?

Tags: mining-hardware

I'd like to buy a mining rig, something like 4 5850 cards, preferably more.  I'd rather not build it myself.  Are there any vendors who sell such machines at a reasonable price?

Answer (score 6):

There are two sites that I know of: [bitcoin-rigs.com](http://www.bitcoin-rigs.com) and [bitcoinrigs.com](http://www.bitcoinrigs.com/)

If you have a local computer shop near you, you could also order the parts and ask them to mount. There is a wiki entry for [mining rigs](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_rig) that has a few standard configurations (including [two](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_rig#Two_ATI_5850s.2C_Approximately_600_Mhash.2Fs) [setups](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_rig#Three_ATI_5850s.2C_Approximately_900_Mhash.2Fs) with 5850s).

You might also want to check the Marketplace section of the [bitcointalk](http://bitcointalk.org) forums. Sometimes people sell used rigs there.